# List.map on columns instead of rows in OCaml

Tags: list, mapping, ocaml

Say I have the following 'a list list:

```
[[a1 ; a2 ; a3];[b1 ; b2 ; b3] ;[c1 ; c2 ; c3]]
```

Is there a way to apply a function f to elements of that list to produce the following using `List.map`?

```
[ f [a1; b1; c1]; f [a2; b2; c2]; f [a3; b3; c3]]
```

I know that List.map iterates through every element of my 'a list list, but it applies the function f on every 'a list (row) in my 'a list list instead of every **column** of my 'a list list

Answer (score 1):

Well, the columns don't exist as values in your data. You might say they exist more as an idea. So there's nothing in the data you can pass to `f` to get your desired result.

You can, of course, create the lists representing the columns and then apply `f` to those.

If your list represents a matrix, you want a list that represents the transpose of the matrix. So one way to proceed would be to write a function to transpose your matrix, then apply `List.map` to that.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jeffrey Scofields answer, below is a definition for a transpose_map function.

```
(**
  Returns a list of list. The i-th element is a list whose first element is
  the i-th element of xs followed by the i-th element of ys.

  For
    xs = [ x1; x2; ...]
    ys = [ [y11; y12; ... ]; [ y21; y22; ... ]; ... ]
  the function gives
    [ [ x1; y11; y12; ... ]; [ x2; y21; y22; ...]; ... ]
  .
*)
let rec list_cons xs ys =
  List.map2 (fun x zs -> x :: zs) xs ys

(** Compute the transpose of a list of list. *)
let rec transpose m =
  match m with
  | [] -> []
  | [a] -> List.map (fun x -> [x]) a
  | hd :: tl -> list_cons hd (transpose tl)

(** Apply a function to the columns of a matrix and return the list of
  transformed columns. *)
let transpose_map f xs = List.map f (transpose xs)
```

Comment: another way to write `transpose` for non-empty matrix: `let rec transpose m = List.map List.hd m :: transpose (List.map List.tl m)`